# Error I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@40db445 time:25828545 in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am creating a small Android application in order to track the Geo locations of the mobile.

I have created a GPSTracking class which extends Service and I have implemented the LocationListener as well.

Since I am building using SDK version 23 I have created a seperate method in order to get permission for below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Below is my method for requesting permission

```
private boolean runtime_permissions(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_GRANTED_CODE);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now in my onCreate method i check for permission and call method enable_buttons

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coordinates = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCoord);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    if(!runtime_permissions()){
        enable_buttons();
    }
}
```

Below is my enable_buttons method which starts and stops my GPS service

```
 private void enable_buttons(){
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CEBGPSTracker.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CEBGPSTracker.class);
            stopService(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

My code works perfectly fine when permission to access location is granted.

Then I tried denying the permission to access location as show below (with never ask again option enabled as shown below)

[image: Permission request]

At this point I am getting a log which repetitively prints below without stopping

04-10 16:07:37.616 14562-14562/com.ceb.transformers I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@40db445 time:27105299 (See logcat.png below)

[image: Logcat]

Could you help me out to understand what's happening here and to get this resolved??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?